# Screen ratio to TV through VGA to HDMI converter

Tags: screen, settings

Hooked up my machine to the TV through a VGA to HDMI converter, but now it defaults to 4:3.

There is no option in screen settings to go to 16:9 as it says "unrecognised display.

I need 16:9 to match my 32 inch TV...

I'm sure this is probably one of those" you're so dumb, here is the answer" questions, and I don't know how to fix it.